# Bank System Deposit/Withdraw

Tags: c#, oop

I am new to C# and expecially to OOP and its principles. So I have a homework from my university to implement a "bank system". I have a deposit, mortgage and loan accounts, also customers, which should be Individual or Companies. I have a formulas for calculating the interest rate for every account but its not important at the moment because i think for the moments this is working fine. My problem is with Deposit function. Here you can see my hierarchy:

**Account.cs**

```
public abstract class Account
{
    private Customer customer;
    private double balance;
    private double interestRate;

    public Customer Customer { get; private set; }
    public double Balance { get; private set; }
    public double InterestRate { get; private set; }

    public Account(Customer customer, double balance, double interestRate)
    {
        this.Customer = customer;
        this.Balance = balance;
        this.InterestRate = interestRate;
    }



    public abstract double CalculateInterestAmount(int numberOfMonths);
    public virtual double Deposit(double amount)
    {
        return this.Balance + amount;
    }        
}
```

**DepositAccount.cs**

```
public class DepositAccount : Account
{
    public DepositAccount(Customer customer, double balance, double interestRate) : base(customer, balance, interestRate)
    { }

    public override double CalculateInterestAmount(int numberOfMonths)
    {
        double interest = 0.0;
        if (this.Balance < 1000)
        {
            interest = 0.0;
        }
        else
        {
            interest = numberOfMonths * this.InterestRate;
        }
        return interest;
    }
    public double Withdraw(double amount)
    {

        double result = 0.0;
        if (amount > this.Balance)
        {
            return result = 0.0;         
        }

        else
        {
            result = this.Balance - amount;
        }


        return result;
    }
}
```

**LoanAccount.cs**

```
public class LoanAccount : Account
{

    public LoanAccount(Customer customer, double balance, double interestRate) : base(customer, balance, interestRate) { }       

    public override double CalculateInterestAmount(int numberOfMonths)
    {
        double interest = 0.0;

        if (this.Customer is IndividualCustomer)
        {
            if (numberOfMonths > 3)
            {
                interest = (numberOfMonths - 3) * this.InterestRate;
            }
            else
            {
                interest = 0.0;
            }

        }

        if (this.Customer is CompanyCustomer)
        {
            if (numberOfMonths > 2)
            {
                interest = (numberOfMonths - 2) * this.InterestRate;
            }
            else
            {
                interest = 0.0;
            }
        }

        return interest;
    }
}
```

**MortgageAccount.cs**

```
public class MortgageAccount : Account
{
    public MortgageAccount(Customer customer, double balance, double interestRate) : base(customer, balance, interestRate)
    { }


    public override double CalculateInterestAmount(int numberOfMonths)
    {
        double interest = 0.0;
        if (this.Customer is CompanyCustomer)
        {
            if (numberOfMonths <= 12)
            {
                interest = (numberOfMonths * this.InterestRate) / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                interest = (((12 * this.InterestRate) / 2) + ((numberOfMonths - 12) * this.InterestRate));
            }
        }

        if (this.Customer is IndividualCustomer)
        {
            if (numberOfMonths <= 6)
            {
                interest = 0.0;
            }
            else
            {
                interest = (numberOfMonths - 6) * this.InterestRate;
            }
        }

        return interest;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Customers
        Customer individual = new IndividualCustomer();
        Customer company = new CompanyCustomer();

        //Accounts
        Account mort = new MortgageAccount(individual, 2500.0, 0.2);     
        Account depo = new DepositAccount(individual, 400, 0.7);
        Account loan = new LoanAccount(company, 10000, 3.2);

        loan.Deposit(999); // this is not working. Balance should be 10999 but it is still 10000
        Console.WriteLine(loan.Balance);
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        accounts.Add(mort);
        accounts.Add(depo);
        accounts.Add(loan);
        Bank b = new Bank(accounts);
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
    }
```

The problem is when I add some amount to any account it returns the same as old. I mean when i debug it is really 10999 but I print 10000. Where is the problem? Also for the method Withdraw only DepositCccounts are allowed to withdraw and when i instantiate the account like this `Account depo = new DepositAccount(individual, 400, 0.7);` the function Withdraw is gone. Should I make `Withdraw` virtual? But i only need it for the DepositAccounts. I am so confused.

Comment: Note that is way too much code. You could (should) have removed all the Interest stuff at least. But still, better then too little code.

Comment: One technical issue that stands out is the `private` setter on Balance. For Withdraw() to work it will have to be `protected`.

Comment: For your design choices, consider posting on the CodeReview site. You'll get less downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Your method to add amount to account is basically returning the sum of two inputs and not storing the data.

You should assign the new value and then return that like so:

```
this.Balance = this.Balance + amount;
return this.Balance;
```

Which can be simplified to one line  using `+=` operator :

```
return this.Balance += amount;
```

For every other operation you should do the same when you want to store that operation. So when you're subtracting amount from the balance you can do :

```
return this.Balance -= amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when I add some amount to any account it returns the same as old. I mean when i debug it is really 10999 but I print 10000. Where is the problem?

Your Deposit method is returning a value (which is then thrown away since you didn't specify any use for it.)  Instead, you want your Deposit method to store the value you've computed.  It doesn't need to return anything.

> Also for the method Withdraw only DepositCccounts are allowed to withdraw and when i instantiate the account like this Account depo = new DepositAccount(individual, 400, 0.7); the function Withdraw is gone.

You can't call Withdraw on an Account, so if you have an Account variable that secretly holds a DepositAccount object you need to typecast to DepositAccount in order to perform the withdrawal.